# Building Visual Studio 2008 solution from command line

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, command-line

I'm trying to automate the building process for a certain open source project. It will do an update on the SVN directory, use CMake to get a .sln file, and build that. I can successfully do this manually, and do svn and cmake from a batch script, but Now I need to build the solution.

A quick google search revealed:

```
devenv /build release /project <projname> <solutionfile>.sln
```

However, that uses the latest version of visual studio (Visual Studio Professional 2011), while the .sln file generated is for Visual C++ Express 2008. I have both versions installed on my computer. Is there a `devenv` I can use for Visual C++ Express 2008? Or is there a commandline argument to specify which version to use?

**UPDATE**

I tried using msbuild, but that didn't seem to like building .vcproj files directly, and I didn't want to build ALL the project files by having it build the .sln file. I ended up using this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcpackages\vcbuild.exe" <myproj>.vcproj "Release|Win32"
```

Comment: Check this link [/Build (devenv.exe)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b20w810z.aspx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong tool to build this. Rather than trying to drive the IDE from the command line you should simply use msbuild.

```
msbuild.exe projectname.proj /property:Configuration=Release
```

In order to set your environment up for the specific version of MSVC you need to call the vcvar.bat file from that specific version. This will set up the necessary environment variables needed by the build tools.

Comment: How might I do that in my scenario?

Comment: (I've worked with msbuild, but not sure how to select version)

Comment: OK, the key is to call vcvars.bat which you'll find somewhere in the VS2008 installation folders (can't remember precisely where). That sets environment vars and everything works from there.

Comment: Ok. I'm building a .sln file... is there any way to specify the .proj file to build (using the code you put in your reply)?

Comment: I don't know how you are building a .sln file, but no matter, I believe you can simply send the .sln file to msbuild and it will build all the projects within.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Got really confused. I can just build the one .proj I want to build... xD

Comment: OK, that sounds like just what you need to do!

Answer (score 2):

For Visual Studio Express 2008 the IDE is called VCExpress.exe. Also you should probably specify the full path of the program when you have two versions installed:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\VCExpress.exe /build release /project <projname> <solutionfile>.sln
```